# Design a style for I.E using CSS?

Tags: html, asp.net, css

I have the following two images.

**Google Chorome**
[image: chorome]

**I.E**
[image: IE]

You can easily see the difference in the designs of both.

and following is the so far stuff in CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
      .main-container
      {
          float:left; margin-left:50px; width:100%;
      }
  </style>

  <!--[if gte IE 6]>
  <style type="text/css">
      .main-container
      {
          float:left; margin-left:50px; width:100%;
      }
  </style>
  <![endif]-->
```

Please help me to make a similar or closer similar design in both browser. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

LIke this please remove `px` in below selector

```
 <!--[if gte IE 6]>
  <style type="text/css">
      .main-container
      {
          float:left; margin-left:50px; width:100%;
      }
  </style>
  <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Please tell what is difference between common and IE specific `CSS`

Comment: @AmitAgrawal http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/internet-explorer.shtml